# How do I get the uid of my Google contacts in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-people-api

I'm writing an app where you can store some lists. Now I want to implements a feature to share these lists with my friends.

So far, I have setup FirebaseAuth with Google login. It works fine (works for multiple accounts over multiple devices).

The structure of my database is something like

```
- users_uid1 
 - List1
     - list of friends gui who are allowed to acces these list (at the moment no entries)
     - subitem1
     - ...
 - List2
 - ...
- users_uid2  
- ...
```

How do I get the emails from my friends via Google API and find the gui from my friends via email-address so I can access their lists?